# Encrypt a string of letters with RSA using C = M^e mod n

Tags: cryptography, rsa

Hi :) I've googled around to understand the meaning of this question: Encrypt the word "SECURITY" with parameters p = 13, q = 19, e = 5. What is the corresponding ciphertext in hexadecimal form?

I used cipher = M^e mod (pq) on each letters corresponding ASCII value. So for S, I wrote: 85^5 mod 247 = 239. Then I proceeded to convert 239 to hexadecimal form: "EF".

Is this the correct way to do it? Doing it letter by letter, and then in the end just add all the hexadecimals together to get the string "EFB388CE3E639121"?

Or should I add the cipher from each letter together and then convert it to hexadecimal form?

```
C(S) = 239, C(E) = 179, C(C) = 136 C(U) = 206 
C(R) = 62,  C(I) = 99,  C(T) = 145, C(Y) = 33



Add them together: 239+179+136 .. = 1099.
Convert 1099 to hexadecimal = 44B.
```

In my opinion it seems meaningless adding them together as several letters can make up the total value of 1099 and that would make it difficult to decrypt, but I just want to be sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can actually encrypt using RSA this way, noting though that the resulting ciphertext is malleable (something that can be fixed by *digitally signing* the plaintext or ciphertext message). It is similar to performing e.g. AES in ECB mode. Normally RSA encryption - as specified in the PKCS#1 standards - is randomized, but yours is not, so the same problems of ECB mode persist: identical letters will be encrypted to the same value, which will make it insecure and vulnerable to frequency analysis. This is *besides* the obvious problem with the RSA key size of course; RSA *requires* specific padding of the input message to be secure.

Do note though that you will want to distinguish the ciphertext of the letters. This means that you should always use the same number of bytes / hexadecimals to encode the number representing the ciphertext. **That means that leading zeros *should be preserved***. This, again, also happens in the PKCS#1 standard (lookup I2OSP which converts an integer to bytes).

Note that in real life we use a *hybrid cryptosystem* where we encrypt a random symmetric key instead of the message itself, and then proceed to encrypt the message with that random key. The wrapped key and ciphertext are then sent together to the recipient.

Answer (score 1):

RSA assumes that your entire message is a single integer `M`, then, just like you say:

```
C = M^e mod N
M = C^d mod N
```

where `N = pq`. This assumes that `M < N`.

If you encode your message `SECURITY` as hex and treat that hex string as a number, you will get:

```
'SECURITY' -> 5345435552495459 -> 6000276112272872537
```

Unfortunately, this number is too large to be encrypted with `N=247`.
I mean, of course, you can "encrypt" it, by passing it through the formula, but you won't be able to recover the original message.

The author of the assignment might mean that you encrypt every letter individually and then concatenate the hex output (just like you did), but that's really weird use of RSA, making the assignment very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first convert every letter to ASCII form, which means:

`M(S) = 83, M(E) = 69, M(C) = 67, M(U) = 85, M(R) = 82, M(I) = 73, M(T) = 84, M(Y) = 89.`

And then you can put the individual numbers together to get the message:

`M = 8369678582738489.`

THEN you can find your ciphertext, before you can find the corresponding number in hexadecimal form.